# Python mocking elasticsearch connection generator `with` statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, mocking, with-statement, python-mock

I would like to test a class with a function that has `with` statement in it:

```
func_to_test():
   ....
   with self.__elastic_generator.get() as es:
      print 'about to use the es connection....'
```

So I mocked the elstic_generator, and I mocked it `get` function when creating the class tested:

```
elastic_gen = mock.Mock()
elstic_gen.get = mock.Mock()
elastic_gen.get.side_effect = ['mocked elastic connection']
tested_class = TestedClass(elastic_gen)
tested_class.func_to_test()
```

But for some reason that doesn't work when using the `with` statement.
However, if getting the connection without using `with`, like this:

`x = self.__elastic_generator.get()`

Then it works fine, and I get `x = 'mocked elastic connection'`.

So I guess the problem is related to some more functions calls being made when using the `with` and that I don't mock these functions.

Can someone please explain what happens under the hood and what else should I mock in order to be able to test it with the `with` statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `with` statement is a concept known as a context manager. A context manager has an `__enter__` function for when you're entering the the `with` and an `__exit__` function for when you're exiting the `with` (either by raising or by execution finishing inside the block).

The `__enter__` function should return the value of whatever you're expecting to be assigned to the variable after `as`, which in this case would be `es`. So, to mock that, you don't want to mock the return value of `.get()`, you want to mock the return value of `.get().__enter__()`. That should look like this:

```
elastic_gen = mock.Mock()
elastic_gen.return_value.__enter__.return_value = 'mocked elastic connection'
```

Comment: Yep. I did something like this, along side with mocking the __exit__ function. Now it's working, thx for explaining